# How to calculate the number of times a particular letter is typed on a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel

I know the title looks enormous but I don't know how to put the title to the question I want to ask.

Ok, basically this is what I have so far:

On the spreadsheet I a column asking a question and the you fill up the row and according what you have there you have to put a Y (yes) or N (no).

On the end of the month we need to know how many Y (yes) we have, I need to do this manually. I was wondering, if there is a way to use a separate cell to count how many Y's we have on that column?

If someone could help on that I will very much appreciate.

Comment: From the ribbon - Formulas ► Function Library group ► More Functions ► Statistical. Look for functions starting with *count* like `COUNTIF`.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely possible. Depending upon which version of Excel you're using (2007 and later should work), try pressing Functions, and then choose AddCount, which counts the amount of something in a certain space.

If this does not work for you, you can also create drop-down menus inside of the Data Validation feature of Excel.

If you're making a form these two options will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column (say column **A**) containing either **Y** or **N,**  then in a cell outside that column enter:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"y")
```

This will perform the counting and will count either upper case or lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Select the excel cell where you want the output. Then go to function box and type **=COUNTIF(CL1:CL100,"Y")**

where CL1 is your stating column Index and 
CL100 is your last column index till where you want to search.